# How do I test for the appearance of a notification in the notification shade?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ios-ui-automation

We are testing an iOS application that works the following way:

- If the user sends the app to the background while performing a task, the app alerts the user to resume the task.
- Tapping on this notification puts the app back into foreground, and it resumes the task.
- The notification text has some content (e.g. numbers) that needs to be parsed against expected values.

I am using Instruments UI Automation's `deactivateAppForDuration` method to push the app into the background - which works fine. On my real test devices, the app is actually pushed into the background.

The problem is in detecting the notification - I have read the UI Automation Documentation and there does not seem to be a way to do this. The only alert-handling construct I found is `onAlert()` which works well for *alert dialogs* only.

So - has any one found a way to handle notifications in the notification shade using UI Automation?